# In Unity, I want to destroy my square when it collides with circle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collision, destroy

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ29I.png)
my square has a rigid body 2D and a box collider 2D.
my circle has a box collider 2D.
The game manager script is just a code to spawn them.
my catcher script is just to move the circle left to right.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ArtDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
  private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
  {
      if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Art"))
      {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Physics` and `Physics2D` are separate in Unity and don't interact with each other.

`OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision2d)` belongs to Physics2D and only responds to Physics2D (BoxCollider2D, CircleCollider2D, PolygonCollider2D, Rigidbody2D, etc.)

`OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)` belongs to Physics and only responds to Physics (BoxCollider, SphereCollider, MeshCollider, Rigidbody, etc.)

You are using `OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)` when you should be using `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ArtDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use OnCollisionEnter2D for 2D!
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Art"))
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for 2D projects you need to use MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D).

Also, I'm not sure how you inserted this code, you can press ctrl + k and paste the snippet next time